# Gnuplot: datapoint labels with alternating offset (above/below data point)

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting a couple of lines in a certain data set. A couple of the data points (column 13 in the example below) are special, I want them to be marked with a circle and labeled (the labels are in column 12).

```
plot "data.csv" using 0:13 with circles lt 3 fs transparent solid 0.3 noborder notitle,\
"data.csv" using 0:13:(sprintf("(%d, %d)", $1, $12)) with labels nopoint offset char 1,-2 notitle,\
"data.csv" using 0:6 with lines lt 7 lw 2
```

I already figured out how to do that. Unfortunately the labels do overlap sometimes, which makes them unreadable.
How can I make the labels appear alternating above/below the data points? I tried to define a function that switches between -1/1, but failed to do so. I also tried to make the offset random by adding

```
"data.csv" using 0:13:(sprintf("(%d, %d)", $1, $12)) with labels nopoint offset char 1,int(-5*(rand(0))) notitle
```

but that also did not work (no visible effect).

Below is an example how the current version looks like (with a couple more plotted lines, I tried to keep the code sample short).
Appreciate any help...

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try to separate the data points into two sets with `every`:

```
plot "data.csv" using 0:13 with circles lt 3 fs transparent solid 0.3 noborder notitle,\
"data.csv" using 0:13:(sprintf("(%d, %d)", $1, $12)) every 2::0 with labels nopoint offset char 1,-2 notitle,\
"data.csv" using 0:13:(sprintf("(%d, %d)", $1, $12)) every 2::1 with labels nopoint offset char 1,2 notitle,\
"data.csv" using 0:6 with lines lt 7 lw 2
```

Then every odd data point has a positive offset; every even data point has a negative offset (or odd <--> even ;-) )

---

**Note:** if you re-use the same source (file) in a comma-separated plot statement, you can use '' instead of repeating 'data.csv'.

Comment: Thank you Tom, your answer helped somewhat, the labels are now above and below. But somehow they are shifted on the x-Axis,like seen on this [picture](http://www.bilderload.com/bild/386652/daxlight04A11.png). Also, is it possible to randomize the offset a bit? Because in my data there is the possibility that three or more of these datapoints are close together... And thx for the hint with the '' shortcut :)

Comment: Just noticed...the uploaded picture uses offset 23,-2 as I fiddled around with your suggestion. In case of offset 1,-2 the labels are shifted even more to the left side

Comment: additional comment: maybe this is due to the structure of the datafile? Not every row in column 13 is populated. Data sample:       2016-04-04;9789.77;9907.05;9732.82;9822.08;9893.85;9655.64;10045.40;9250.40;9779.70;;;
2016-04-05;9647.81;9661.30;9553.17;9563.36;9832.69;9722.31;9975.32;9316.25;9779.70;Kijun Cross;neutral\nSHORT;9722.309570
2016-04-06;9582.46;9635.91;9505.90;9624.51;9809.05;9722.31;9862.12;9316.25;9779.70;;;
2016-04-07;9648.55;9702.18;9484.75;9530.62;9791.22;9791.64;9952.90;9327.75;9779.70;Tenkan/Kijun Cross;weak\nSHORT;9791.219727'    (hope this is readable...)